# Get ancestor route params in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have the following  route hierarchy :

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {
     path: 'article',
     component: ArticleComponent,
     children: [
     {
         path: '',
         component: ArticleListComponent
     },
     {
         path: ':articleId',
         component: ArticleDetailComponent,
          children: [
          {
              path: '',
              component: PageListComponent
          },
          {
              path: ':pageId',
              component: PageComponent
          }]
     }]
 },
  {path: '**', component: DefaultComponent},
];
```

When I click the `Article` link , the page is navigated to :

"https://run.plnkr.co/article;listData=foo"

And then I see this :

[image]

Now , When I click at `Article 2` , the page is navigated to

"https://run.plnkr.co/article;listData=foo/2;detailData=bar"

And then I see this :

[image]

Now , when I click at the `Page 33` link ,  the page is navigated to :

"https://run.plnkr.co/article;listData=foo/2;detailData=bar/33;detailData=kro"

And then I see this:

[image]

**OK**

As you can see ,  at the innermost component ( the single page component) , I set some code to see the *current* params :

```
Page  component! {{params | json}}
```

Which is populated in :

```
export class PageComponent {
   constructor(private activatedRoute_:ActivatedRoute) {
    activatedRoute_.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.params=params;
      });
  }
```

**Question:**

Currently the value of  `params` value - is only `{ "pageId": "33", "detailData": "kro" }` which belongs to the final route.

But how can I get the previous routes values ?

*I know I can read the querystring but I find it an unconventional way .*

The innermost url is  :

"https://run.plnkr.co/article;listData=foo/2;detailData=bar/33;detailData=kro"

So basically I'm asking how can I extract  all the parameters from prev routes.

( I mean what are the values for `articleId` , `listData` , `detailsData` <sub>(the first one)</sub> )?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O6XaDbcoBVnOox4bwNK1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all parents params using snapshot. In detail component:

```
let node = activatedRoute_.snapshot;
while(node) {
  console.log('component', node.component.name, ', params:', node.params);
  node = node.parent;
}

 component ArticleDetailComponent , 
            params: Object {articleId: "1", detailData: "bar"}
 component ArticleComponent , params: Object {listData: "foo"}
 component RootComponent , params: Object {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be sending the `listData` value along with the object.Modify this to your `app/article-list.component.ts` Component

```
<a [routerLink]="[articleId, {listData:'foo',detailData: 'bar'}]">
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yQ4ncCf1T46WTL5s5Hhi?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

You can manually send params when calling the states inside the links, but to be honest this is not the best solution. 
My better suggestion is to use the resolve blocks of the states and implement resolvers in order to achieve that.

Every state will have the corresponding resolver which will resolve the params you need from the previous state. 
Here the link to the documentation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html

The concept is that inside the resolve of the i state, you can still access the state parameters of the i-1 state, so you can pass them to the new state.